# How to get File within' package, in an Android application

Tags: java, android, file, package

I'm am creating an Android application, but in order to have one of the functionalities working I need to read a predefined xml file whilst only knowing its name, not the R.id..

In normal Java I know I can use

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(xmlName)`

but using the limited Android SDK thats not working, any knows how to solve this?

Comment: You mean you're trying to read it out of the jar file itself right?

Comment: Well, in this instance the .apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getResources().getIdentifier()` from your `Context` (e.g., `Activity`), but please cache the result if you will use it more than once. `getIdentifier()` is implemented on [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Data Storage Section in the android developer manual](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html):

> If you have a static file to package with your application at compile time, you can save
>   the file in your project in res/raw/myDataFile, and then open it with
>   Resources.openRawResource (R.raw.myDataFile). It returns an InputStream object that you can
>   use to read from the file.

Comment: The poster indicated that the problem is not having R.raw.myDataFile available.